# Cancel graphQL call on component unmount

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-hooks, recyclerlistview

I am using below @apollo/GraphQL query inside a React native component

```
const [getContent, {
    error, data, fetchMore, called
  }] = useLazyQuery(BROWSE_CONTENT, {
    variables: {
      sessionIdToken: sessionId,
      deviceLocale,
      paginationCursor: `'${payload.endCursor}'`
    }
  })
```

Once i have data, I use RecyclerListView to render the list.

Problem: since its async call (**useLazyQuery**), so if user quickly change the View (by clicking the button) i am getting below error.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in RecyclerListView (at MyComponent.js:345)
```

How to cancel useLazyQuery on component unmount.

Comment: useLazyQuery is a React hook, use it for functional component only (no lifecycle methods). Posting full source of MyComponent.js will help

Comment: @SonNguyen I'll try to create a sample code. Can u give me an example to render something by using functional component only (no lifecycle methods)

Comment: @SonNguyen In my case i am getting all the inputs as prop, only useLazyQuery is the only react hook i am using